# WriteableBitmap.WritePixels -> Buffer size is not sufficient

Tags: c#, bitmap

I'm working on a mandelbrot fractal renderer and managed to get a basic version working. As a next step I tried to make the writing to the bitmap in chunks so the user gets faster feedback. Doing this, I ran into an error on calling the WritePixels method on my WriteableBitmap ("Buffer size is not sufficient").

```
var bytesPerPixel = _bitmap.Format.BitsPerPixel/8;
var stride = _bitmap.PixelWidth*bytesPerPixel;
var imageBytes = new byte[stride*_bitmap.PixelHeight];
var chunks = _bitmap.PixelHeight;
var chunkSize = _bitmap.PixelWidth;
for (var chunk = 0; chunk < chunks; chunk++)
{
    var chunkPixelIndex = chunk*chunkSize;
    for (var pixel = chunkPixelIndex; pixel < chunkPixelIndex+chunkSize; pixel++)
    {
        ColorPixel(pixel, bytesPerPixel, imageBytes);
    }
    var imageRect = new Int32Rect(0, 0, _bitmap.PixelWidth, _bitmap.PixelHeight);
    _bitmap.WritePixels(imageRect, imageBytes, stride, chunkPixelIndex*bytesPerPixel);
}
```

Here's the last know working version of the code for comparison:

```
var bytesPerPixel = _bitmap.Format.BitsPerPixel/8;
var stride = _bitmap.PixelWidth*bytesPerPixel;
var imageBytes = new byte[stride*_bitmap.PixelHeight];
var numberOfPixels = _bitmap.PixelWidth*_bitmap.PixelHeight;
for (var pixel = 0; pixel < numberOfPixels; pixel++)
{
    ColorPixel(pixel, bytesPerPixel, imageBytes);
}
var imageRect = new Int32Rect(0, 0, _bitmap.PixelWidth, _bitmap.PixelHeight);
_bitmap.WritePixels(imageRect, imageBytes, stride, 0);
```

EDIT: Using the debugger I've established that the first time the code throws is when it's calling WritePixels with an offset of 4320 (1080*4). imageBytes has a size of 3110400 so I really don't see how it's size isn't sufficient. Am I just blatantly misunderstanding this api?